# I made a moving screensaver in c++ console but there is a bug when it hits the corner

Tags: c++, console-application, game-physics

you know the screensavers on old dvd players? I made it in the console using ascii but when it hits a corner it goes out of sight. I'm not sure what is happening, it should work. I'm just messing around and trying to learn so it's not a big deal but if anyone is interested in taking a look I would be very grateful! Also any general feedback and advice would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int width = 20;
int height = 10;
int iconX, iconY;
enum eDirection {UPLEFT,UPRIGHT,DOWNRIGHT,DOWNLEFT}dir;
int lastDir;

void Setup()
{
    dir = UPRIGHT;                //sets the direction and a
    iconX = rand() % width + 1;   //random starting point
    iconY = rand() % height + 1;

}

void Draw()
{
    system("cls");//clear the screen each frame
    for (int y = 0; y < height + 2; y++) { // this goes from top to bottom of the grid
        for (int x = 0; x < width + 2; x++) { // and then left to right to hit every square with these conditionals
            if (y == 0 || y == height + 1) cout << "-"; //top and bottom border
            if ((x == 0 || x == width + 1) && (y != 0 && y != height + 1)) cout << "|"; // both sides
            if (x == iconX && y == iconY) cout << "0"; // this is the icon that will bounce around the screen
            else if ((y != 0 && y != height + 1) && (x != 0 && x != width+1)) cout << " "; // if the icon wasn't drawn and 
        }                                                               //we aren't currently on a border it makes a space
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Move()
{   //bounces on the sides
    if (iconX == 1 || iconX == width) {
        switch (lastDir) {
        case 0:
            dir = UPRIGHT;   //this code checks if the icon is right
            break;           //next to a wall and depending on which        
        case 1:              //direction it was moving it is given a 
            dir = UPLEFT;    //new direction to move in
            break;
        case 2:
            dir = DOWNLEFT;
            break;
        case 3:
            dir = DOWNRIGHT;
            break;
        }
    }
    //bounces on the top and bottom
    if (iconY == 1 || iconY == height) {
        switch (lastDir) {
        case 0:
            dir = DOWNLEFT;  //same thing down here but for
            break;           //the top and bottom
        case 1:             
            dir = DOWNRIGHT;
            break;
        case 2:
            dir = UPRIGHT;
            break;
        case 3:
            dir = UPLEFT;
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (dir) {
    case UPLEFT: 
        iconX--;     //this code moves the icon 
        iconY--;     //depending on which direction 
        break;       //is currently saved in dir
    case UPRIGHT:
        iconX++;
        iconY--;
        break;
    case DOWNLEFT:
        iconX--;
        iconY++;
        break;
    case DOWNRIGHT:
        iconX++;
        iconY++;
        break;
    }
    lastDir = dir; //it saves the last direction
}                  //as a number to be used to do 
                   //the bouncing
int main()
{
    Setup();
    while (true) {
        Draw();   
        Move();   
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Replacing your `case 0, 1, 2, 3` with `case UPLEFT, UPRIGHT, DOWNRIGHT, DOWNLEFT` when you switch on `lastDir` would help with readability so I don't have to keep scrolling up to see which is which.

Comment: Specifically looking at the bottom right corner (this applies for all your other corners), you change direction based on `x` position, but then also change direction based on `y` position. Your `y` position change overwrites your `x` position change. When the icon is moving DOWNRIGHT and hits the bottom right corner, its new direction is set to UPRIGHT and it moves off screen. Never to bounce back into frame.

Comment: You seem to be repeating your logic a few times. Have you considered tracking the left-right direction independently of the up-down direction? You would need two variables to store the last direction, but there would also be code simplification. Plus your bug might just vaporize...

Comment: I'm going to try implementing JaMiT idea of just doing a x direction and y direction and then combining the two. but with the two if statements in sequence and the y (top and bottom) happening second it shouldn't matter if it overwrites because it didn't move yet and y if statement will switch the direction again

Comment: hey hey, she's fixed! check her out
`

Answer (score 0):

she's fixed! check her out. shout out to @JaMiT for the idea

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int width = 20;
int height = 10;
int iconX, iconY;
enum Vertical {UP,DOWN}vert;
enum Horizontal {LEFT,RIGHT}hor;
int lastVert;
int lastHor;

void Setup()
{
   vert = UP;                //sets the direction and a
   hor = LEFT;
   iconX = rand() % width + 1;   //random starting point
   iconY = rand() % height + 1;

}

void Draw()
{
   system("cls");//clear the screen each frame
   for (int y = 0; y < height + 2; y++) { // this goes from top to bottom of the grid
       for (int x = 0; x < width + 2; x++) { // and then left to right to hit every square with these conditionals
           if (y == 0 || y == height + 1) cout << "-"; //top and bottom border
           if ((x == 0 || x == width + 1) && (y != 0 && y != height + 1)) cout << "|"; // both sides
           if (x == iconX && y == iconY) cout << "0"; // this is the icon that will bounce around the screen
           else if ((y != 0 && y != height + 1) && (x != 0 && x != width+1)) cout << " "; // if the icon wasn't drawn and 
       }                                                               //we aren't currently on a border it makes a space
       cout << endl;
   }
}

void Move()
{
   if (iconX == 1 || iconX == width)
       if (lastHor == 0) //0 is left
           hor = RIGHT;
       else
           hor = LEFT;

   if (iconY == 1 || iconY == height)
       if (lastVert == 0) //0 is up
           vert = DOWN;
       else
           vert = UP;

   if (vert == UP)iconY--;
   else iconY++;
   if (hor == LEFT)iconX--;
   else iconX++;

   lastVert = vert;
   lastHor = hor;
}

int main()
{
   Setup();
   while (true) {
       Draw();   
       Move();   
   }                   
}
```

Comment: I could not figure out how to put the enum variable vert or hor into another variable that would keep it the same, so I just used the int to store it and used it's index for the if statement. Also I watched it bounce out of a corner successfully!